# Activity transition not working jellybean

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom_webpage, R.anim.freeze);` between my activities to show the transition. The transition works fine on Gingerbread but not on JellyBean. What could be the prob? I checked similar questions here but none of them solved my problem.

slide_in_from_bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="300"
/>
</set>
```

freeze.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="300"
/>
</set>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check whether Transition Animation Scale is set in settings:

Settings->Developer options -> Transition animation scale